# Does Smart Folio Case for IPad Pro work in Mac using Universal Control?

Tags: macos, ipad

I connected Smart Folio Keyboard to iPad, and turned on universal control in both Mac and IPad. But the Smart Folio Keyboard is not working in Mac.

For my trackpad, it works across both devices. The Bluetooth keyboard connected to Mac also works across both devices. The Smart Folio keyboard, however, only works in Mac.

Can the Smart Folio keyboard work as an universal control device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying out a similar set up, I managed to get the Smart Folio Case to work as the keyboard for the Mac if you use the iPad as an Extended Display for the Mac. Currently running using an iPad Air 4 and a Mac Mini 2022

Comment: You need to explain it a bit more to make it a better answer.